# Why can't I deploy .Net Maui project to physical device?

Tags: xamarin, maui

I have a .Net Maui app.

I used to test on an android physical device. Everything was working fine. But recently, I can't deploy any more. I'm getting the following error :

```
    Error   XARDF7024   System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty.

       à System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound, WIN32_FIND_DATA& data)
       à System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost)
       à Xamarin.Android.Tasks.RemoveDirFixed.RunTask() P99-SoireeSympa C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.440\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   2449
```

The project compiles properly. The error is raised only when trying to deploy to an android device.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Delete any existing installs first

Comment: @Jason Yes, I've uninstalled the previous app. Any other ideas please ?

Comment: @Jason Any idea which directory needs to be empty please ?

Comment: Try deploy to device B to see if any settings different from device A. Or remove bin and obj and rebuild.

Comment: It has to do with missing or corrupted certain files. You can run Check Disk to see if there are some hidden files under the folder.